# Center container divs in different resolutions

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-isotope

I am building portfolio website using bootstraper and isotope js. I have `container` div. On desktop browser view `container` contains 3 divs in one line and all looking good, but when resolution changed and number of divs decreased(less than two per line) - in that case the divs are not centered.

```
<div id="container" class="clearfix isotope" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; height: 680px;">
    <div class="element item col-md-4 isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1, 1); opacity: 1;">
        <div class="view view-first">
            //content
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="element item col-md-4 isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-transform: translate(320px, 0px) scale(1, 1); opacity: 1;">
        <div class="view view-first">
            //content
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="element item col-md-4 isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-transform: translate(640px, 0px) scale(1, 1); opacity: 1;">
        <div class="view view-first">
            //content
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="element item col-md-4 isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 340px) scale(1, 1); opacity: 1;">
        <div class="view view-first">
            //content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do you fix that?

Comment: position: absolute; + responsive == headheache

Comment: taking a `headache` of developing for different resolutions this responsive `headache` is far better!!

Comment: @Yashhy Oups .. typos .. h kind. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code is not working or well formed the way it is presented in your question. Is there a stray closing tag `</div>` in the second `<div class="element item col-md-4 isotope-item"` ?

I [jsfiddled it here](http://jsfiddle.net/7Npde/1/) and `style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;` will overlap every containers to top left.

If you look at [that bootstrap example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/) code, you will notice the specified the behavior of a container for dirrenent viewport size like so :

```
<div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
```

I recommend you to read [bootstrap grid-options](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options) so you get a better comprehension about how to use it.

Hope this helps